# What are the ways to record raw video?

Tags: camera, video

I have a camera (OV2311) connected to my raspberry pi4.

I want to learn what are the ways to record RAW video (fps 1) .

I don't know if this is possible with the rpicam-vid application, so I am asking in general from where should I start?

(btw, I searched and there is another similar question whose answer is "use picamera library in python". Unfortunately that library is obsolete and not available anymore. )